# How to add layout within a layout in tabs

Tags: android, layout, tabs, android-linearlayout

I want to be able to get something similar to [this..](http://lh5.ggpht.com/xm1Kzomfd_25hFU42RHLRNXMSKWFavNT8J93ouF5njxn9mXXRHFJlFrauDtorXdieNoNvN22HVtNMThBKA)

I want to be able to add the text views inside the tabs...
This has to be done dynamically.. as in when the add button is clicked in another activity the text views should be aligned similar to this and the data from that form should be added here...
Please tell me how this can be done by code.
How can I add Text Views in this particular format or layout to the tabs?

Comment: the rules of the site are that you should go explore before you ask a question, there are many posts simmilar to what you are asking. For future be careful otherwise you'll never be able to get good reputation on stackoverflow.com

Comment: I did look around plenty.. I only ended up posting this because i wasn't able to find out by myself as to how i could go about getting the desired result.. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: apart from that you should ask specific question's not how to generate whole UI. Edit your question and ask some specific question that you are having trouble with and will be glad to help.

Comment: My bad... new to android development.. will make sure of it the next time:) and thanks for your help. will look around a lot better next time before posting here.

Comment: @Mayank in the image i have given has listview been used to show the subjects 1 below the other?

Comment: what about listView? what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like simple ListView insde a Tab.

so you create TabActivity which will add bunch of tabs, than on  each tab you can add different activity and populate activity with Data.

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec; // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

// Do the same for the other tabs
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SomeActivity.class);
tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabname").setIndicator("TabName").setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you look at example code on [`AndroidDeveloper`](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html), you can see, they are actually adding the tabs programmatically.

Everything you have to do, is to implement it to your code.

**We are no code-free service, we're only advisors ;-)**

Comment: Sorry.. my bad. should have looked around more attentively. I found what i was looking for. Thank You